# Can anybody let me know the command to obtain the current maximum size to store the object in the Memcached

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, memcached

Can anybody let me know the command to obtain the current maximum size to store the object in the Memcached.
 In the documentation I have not come across getting the actual size of my Memcached capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available in the output of `stat settings` command.
I didn't get if you wanted the maximum size of a single item or the total available memory but both are available.

**Maximum item size**

(at least in not too old releases, I checked with 1.4.13). Using telnet:

```
telnet <hostname> <port>
> stat settings
(...)
item_size_max 1048576
(...)
```

**Maximum capacity in bytes**

Available both in `stat` and `stat settings`:

```
telnet <hostname> <port>
> stat settings
(...)
maxbytes 10737418240
(...)
> stat
(...)
limit_maxbytes 10737418240
(...)
```

**Remaining capacity**

As far as I know, it's not directly available, you have to compute it from `stat` command output:

```
> stat
(...)
bytes 5349380740
(...)
limit_maxbytes 10737418240
(...)
```

Here I have `limit_maxbytes - bytes` = 5388037500 bytes remaining.

**Documentation**

This is confirmed by the documentation shipped with sources, in `doc/protocol.txt`:

```
| maxbytes          | size_t   | Maximum number of bytes allows in this cache |   
| item_size_max     | size_t   | maximum item size                            |
```

**Side note**

Note that this is only memory consumption and memory limit from a memcached point of view. The limit is the one that has been given in command line with `-m` option. It won't tell you if the physical memory is not sufficient to handle that much data.

Comment: It's maximum size of the single Item, which I set using -I from the command line. Thanks for the answer :)